# Token based authentication in spa (React)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, single-page-application

As I realized refresh token not supported in spa (react) . 
Because it can not protect it .

So  series of questions came up to me :

**1 - Can we use long time access token in spa ? Is it secure?**

**2 - Is alternative solution for refresh token?**

**3 - Should we use the 3rd party identity server such as identityserver 4 or we can implement token generation Ourselves). What is best practice?**

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but still...

You are right in terms of that **refresh token** should not be returned by **Implicit Grant** which is used to authenticate users in SPA applications. And yes, the limitation is due to a browser is unable to keep it private.

> 1 - Can we use long time access token in spa ? Is it secure?

We can, but whether it will be secure would depend on your application's security policy.
To keep it short, [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/access-token-lifetime/) is an example of how you can consider Access Token Lifetime to be specified for various security requirements.

> 2 - Is alternative solution for refresh token?

Yes, it is called **Silent Authentication** and briefly it looks like this:

- a client (SPA app) obtains an Access Token and **expires_in** parameter
- Identity Server provides an auth session (cookie) so the app can request a new token without providing credentials since it's already authenticated at Identity Server
- in case of session's sliding expiration a client pings Identity Server to keep the session alive as long as needed
- once the Acces Token becomes expired and auth session is alive (a check might be needed), a client requests for another Access Token (this is usually done in a `setTimeout`), but in this case providing a parameter to tell an Identity Server that consent screen should be dropped (usually it is `prompt=none`)

Resources:

[Azure AD Silent authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad)

[Auth0 Silent authentication](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication)

> 3 - Should we use the 3rd party identity server such as identityserver 4 or we can implement token generation Ourselves). What is best
>   practice?

That would depend on the size of your application and whether you need just a token generation or something more (like Federated authentication out-of-the-box, various grant types, etc.).
For big enterprises (if there's no need to reinvent the wheel) it is always the best practice to use a production-ready 3rd party library ([Identity Server 4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) or [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core)) unless you have a small application (MVP, prototype, etc.).

Identity Server 4 needs some effort to configure it the right way and may simply be excessive. OpenIddict is a bit easier alternative.

Custom token generation is something that we used to do before Identity Server emerged. Today it is only a matter of having a quick solution for your custom authentication needs.

Worth to mention this project [JWTSimpleServer](https://github.com/Xabaril/JWTSimpleServer) for simple JWT authentication.